# django try block best use

Tags: python, django, try-catch

I have a view that takes 2 arguments :course_slug and chapter_slug  and i want to check if the given course and chapter exist in the database so what's the best way to do that :

```
def Chapter_Detail(request,course_slug,chapter_slug):
    try:
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    except Course.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("course does not exist")
    
    try:
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(slug=chapter_slug)
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("chapter does not exist")
    
    '''
    continue view logic 
    '''
    
    context = {
        'chapter':chapter,
        'course' :course,
        
    }

    return render(request,'courses/chapter-detail.html',context)
```

or:

```
def Chapter_Detail(request,course_slug,chapter_slug):
    try:
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(slug=chapter_slug)
        '''
        continue view logic 
        '''
    except Course.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("course does not exist")
    
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("chapter does not exist")
    
    
    
    
    context = {
        'chapter':chapter,
        'course' :course,
        
    }

    return render(request,'courses/chapter-detail.html',context)
```

or:

```
def Chapter_Detail(request,course_slug,chapter_slug):
    try:
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(slug=chapter_slug)
        
    except Course.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("course does not exist")
    
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("chapter does not exist")
    
    else : 
        '''
        continue view logic 
        '''

    
    
    context = {
        'chapter':chapter,
        'course' :course,
        
    }

    return render(request,'courses/chapter-detail.html',context)
```

or there is a better way

continue view logic means that we are going to work with  the course and chapter objects

Comment: It would be helpful to see the models.py. You can likely perform a get_or_404 with the two slugs but you might be able to better relate your databases to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: i have 2 models : a course model and a chapter model  both  with a slug field

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Aiden, you can use the shortcut specifically made for this.

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def Chapter_Detail(request,course_slug,chapter_slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=course_slug)
    chapter = get_object_or_404(Chapter, slug=chapter_slug)
    '''
    continue view logic
    '''
    context = {
        'chapter':chapter,
        'course' :course,
    }
    return render(request,'courses/chapter-detail.html',context)
```

Your three variants will also work of course. The `else`-block in the third example is strictly not necessary, since either error will get `raised` or code will proceed.